# Changing css property dyamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

```
.gridArea {
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 98%;
  overflow: auto;
  border: solid 1px #333366;
}
```

If I have the above css class defined in a file xyz.css and I want to change dynamically the property from "overflow" to "hidden" using JavaScript, how can it be done ?

Comment: two ways I would try it is with the .attr() method, or creating a second class that does what you want and using the addClass() and removeClass() methods

Comment: @mmeasor This is jQuery, he's asking for javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you can apparently alter the css, some guy explains it [Here](http://www.omnimint.com/A6/JavaScript/Change-external-CSS-stylesheet-file-with-JavaScript.html)

or you can change the elements instead of touching the css

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gridArea');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style["overflow"]="hidden";
}​
```

or if you are willing to try jQUery(which is simply a free javascript extension, you can do it in one line:

```
$(".gridArea").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to change the property for both current and future elements is to override the `overflow` property's value in a dynamically created stylesheet element:

```
var s = document.createElement('style');
s.innerHTML = '.gridArea {overflow: hidden;}';
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(s);
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/galicuto/1/edit

If you only need to change the value for a single element, you could change it via the style property:

```
var el = document.querySelector('.gridArea');
el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

If you want to change it for all the elements currently in the document, you can do the same, but iterate over the results given by `document.querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Using Query Selector

```
var el = document.querySelector('.gridArea');
el.style.overflow = "hidden";
```